# Um pequeno probleminha no Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Havia, ontem, feito uma pergunta aqui mesmo no site em relação a um problema em meu Eclipse ADT. Agradeço de coração ao felizardo, cujo nome não estou lembrado, por ter me ajudado! O jeito foi instalar um plugin no SDK.

Mesmo assim, ao construir meus projetinhos Android no Eclipse ADT, acredito que a IDE sugere-me uma modificação no código (essas lâmpadas!). Vejam o que estou a falar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse modelo de código não aparecia quando havia instalado o plugin do ADT há alguns dias, e nem aparecia as lâmpadas.

Se há algum problema ou melhoria no código, o que eu faço?

Comment: Nomes de objetos/propriedades/métodos em sublinhado estão depreciados não é recomendado utilizar eles, a lampada deve ser uma sugestão do recurso novo ou similar.

Comment: Você pode ver o histórico da sua participação aqui no site acedendo ao seu [perfil](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/23601/gabriel). Para saber o porquê das lâmpadas coloque o ponteiro do rato por cima delas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nomes de objetos/propriedades/métodos etc. em sublinhado estão obsoletos, não é recomendado utilizar eles em novos projetos, a lâmpada deve ser uma sugestão do recurso novo ou similar.

A classe `ActionBarActivity` está obsoleta conforme indica a [documentação](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html) no lugar dela deve ser utilizada a [AppCompatActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html)

Mude:

```
public class Tela extends ActionBarActivity
```

Para:

```
public class Tela extends AppCompatActivity
```

Comment: Hummm.. entendi... faço o quê agora?

Comment: Seguindo os "conselhos" das lâmpadas, consegui removê-las.

O que houve no meu código: acrescémio da instrução: @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") 

Mesmo assim, o sublinhado ainda existe!

Comment: No lugar de `public class tela extends ActionBarActivity` coloque `public class tela extends AppCompatActivity`, e faça o import correto que seja sugerido pelo eclipse. @Gabriel

Comment: VALEEEEU! Tudo correu nos conformes! Existe algum lugar neste tópico onde eu possa marcar a questão como resolvida?

Comment: Sim no lado esquerdo tem umas setas abaixo delas tem um `V` que sinaliza que essa resposta foi aceita, aproveite e veja [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/91). @Gabriel